# PSTricks: Newly introduced error in package

Tags: pstricks, compilation-error

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

It produces the error

```
Runaway argument?
] {pgffor.code.tex} 
! Paragraph ended before \ProvidesPackageRCS@i was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.11
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: The only way currently imho is to go back to an older pgf version until pstricks is fixed (I wrote the author already)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hi Ulrike. Thanks for the answer. Do you know where I can find an older version of PGF? `:-)`

Comment: You could try to replace in a local copy of pstricks.tex (you find it in tex/generic) `\def\ProvidesPackageRCS{\@ifnextchar[\ProvidesPackageRCS@i{\ProvidesPackageRCS@i[] }}%$` by `\def\ProvidesPackageRCS#1{}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That did the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: To whom do you send a bug report?

Comment: @Herbert to you. I wrote to the tug address mentioned in pstricks.sty.

Comment: hm, I didn't get any mail ...

Comment: @Herbert I was already a bit wondering that you didn't answer. I just sent another mail as test. Did you get it?

Comment: no, there is somthing wrong on my side ... have to investigate

Comment: @Herbert spam filter?

Comment: No, a problem with the mailer ... :-(

Comment: @Herbert I had sent you spam emails about `fancyvrb` at that same address... they are not very focused but maybe start reading from the latest (once you get time, nothing urgent)

Comment: @jfbu: mail is fixed, but all old mails are lost ...

Comment: @Herbert get ready, I have sent it again `:)`

Comment: @jfbu: Got it and will upload a new `fancyvrb`

Comment: @Herbert thanks, I had not noticed yet that your 3.2 update had already silently made its way to my computer...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Update

This fix is no longer needed in current tex systems. MikTeX users should keep in mind that they may have to run the updater in admin *and* user mode in case the involved packages reside in different trees of a multi-user installation.

### Old Answer

Until pstricks has been adapted to the new pgf version you could try to 
replace in a local copy of pstricks.tex (you find it in tex/generic)

```
\def\ProvidesPackageRCS{\@ifnextchar[\ProvidesPackageRCS@i{\ProvidesPackageRCS@i[] }}%$
```

by

```
\def\ProvidesPackageRCS#1{}
```

Comment: Just to mention that the update has been available in MikTeX and TeX live for quite a while now. So an update of the system should fix things. MikTeX users should keep in mind that they may have to run the updater in admin *and* user mode in case the involved packages reside in different trees of a multi-user installation (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864).

Comment: @moewe I have edited the answer. And I really hope that my feature request leads to something, I think we had (at least) five user/admin woes in the last three days.

Answer (score 6):

use `pstricks.tex` from http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/generic/pstricks/
or wait one or two days for the update. It has a slightly other solution.

Comment: I didn't try to make a real solution - suppressing all message are naturally not right.

Comment: There is only a problem, if someone uses a  development version  of `pstricks.tex` and an old pgf. Later it will be the same as you already suggested.

Comment: Sorry. Where is the horizontal `0` labels in my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469216/87876)?

Answer (score 2):

For `texlive-pstricks` in MacPorts, it worked to uninstall and deactivate `pgf` and then install `pgf-devel` (on 2019-03-15).