# pgf package + pstricks | MikTeX | still 'broken'

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, pstricks, incompatibility

So, after waiting until today (Jan. 8) to try updating pgf for my MikTeX install(s), went ahead and gave it a try (first after backing everything up in my MikTeX root directories).

Install pgf using MikTeX update console. The package information for the update is v. 3.1, build 7 January, 16:11 EST 2019.

However, for any document using some of the PSTricks packages I use, updating pgf causes some compile errors. Here is an mwe, with the error message at the bottom:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{article}

 %% uncommenting any of the following causes a compile error
 % \usepackage{pst-node}
 %  \usepackage{pstricks-add}
 %  \usepackage{pst-func}

 \begin{document}

 here is some text...

 \end{document}
```

If you uncomment any of the PS packages, you get the following error(s) -- here, after uncommenting pst-node:

```
 Command Line:   latex.exe --enable-write18 --src "mwe_pgf.tex"
 Startup Folder: E:\books\mark2019\misc code\mwe

 This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930 64-bit)
 entering extended mode
 (mwe_pgf.tex
 LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
 (<snip>...
 (\MikTeX\tex/generic/pstricks\pstricks.tex
 (\MikTeX\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.tex
 `pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
 (\MikTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex
 (C:\Users\egc\Desktop\egc\text\MikTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil- 
 common-lists.tex))
  (\MikTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
 (\MikTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))

 (\MikTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex
 Runaway argument?
 ] {pgffor.code.tex} 
 ! Paragraph ended before \ProvidesPackageRCS@i was complete.
 <to be read again> 
                    \par 
 l.11 

 ?
```

Updated pgf now plays nice with tikz (as far as I can tell), but not PSTricks. Which creates an enormous problem for people who use the latter.

If anyone can confirm the issue at their end, I'll post a bug report. Until then, back to the old (but still working) pgf package for me.

Comment: Use [@Herbert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469005/pstricks-newly-introduced-error-in-package). It works for me.

Comment: by the way: This site is not a bug tracker. Write in such cases to the author!