# pstricks-add.sty: ERROR

Tags: pstricks

The newest update update of *pstricks-add* gives me the following error:

*! Paragraph ended before \ProvidesPackageRCS@i was completed*

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know, how to fix this?

Comment: There was a version issue with the newly released Ti*k*Z/PGF that I think should already be resolved. Try to update again (in both admin and user mode if you use MikTeX). The example compiles fine for me with a recently updated MikTeX (but MikTeX is often a bit behind TeX live, so if there are new issues, those won't have hit me yet).

Comment: Update your system and it will be ok.

Comment: This should be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469005/35864