# error paragraph ended before \ProvidesPackageRCSi was complete

Tags: errors

I'm new using LaTeX and in this moment I have a problem with the next code, i appreciate your helping, next I will show u my code and then my error:

code

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[journal=jacs]{chemstyle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
%Paquetes necesarios para tablas
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortab}
\decimalpoint                           %Usa como separador decimal el punto en lugar de la coma

\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{subfigure}                                      %Crea subfiguras
\usepackage{color}                      %Paquete emplado para manipular los colores
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                                           %Encabezados y pies de pagina
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\usepackage{multicol}   
\usepackage{listings}                     %Paquete para agregar codigo
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

%Formato del título de las secciones

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\large}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\normalsize}

%Creación del ambiente anexos
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{anexo}{thp}{anx}
\floatname{anexo}{Anexo}
\restylefloat{anexo}
\restylefloat{figure}


%Modificación del formato de los captions
\usepackage[margin=10pt,labelfont=bf]{caption}

%Paquete para incluir comentarios
\usepackage{todonotes}

%Paquete para incluir hipervínculos
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, 
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = black,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\checkmark$}

\mbox{
    \begin{minipage}{5cm}
        \includegraphics[width=7cm]{minas.png} 
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{13cm}
    \begin{center}
        \textsl{
        \textbf{\large Laboratorio de Hormigón I.}\\
        \textbf{\large Profesora: Lucia Salazar Estrada.}}
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{\LARGE{Práctica IV Mezcla del concreto hidráulico. }}\\
    \textbf{Desarrollo de ensayos para normas NTC 396 y NTC 1926}\\
    \vspace{7mm}
        \textbf{\large{Juan Manuel Julio Bedoya}}\\
        Estudiante de ingeniería civil.\\
    \textbf{\large{Julián Andrés Lastra García}}\\
        Estudiante de ingeniería civil.\\
    \vspace{4mm}
    \textbf{\large{Grupo 5}}\\
    \today
\end{center}

\vspace{7mm}

\end{document}
```

error

> line 11 paragraph ended before \ProvidesPackageRCSiwascomplete.to be
>   read again...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! When I replace `minas.png` with a file that exists on my system and compile your code with `xelatex`, I do not get any error. Which compiler do you use? In order to debug the error, you may remove all but the necessary packages, and then see what happens.

Comment: please make a more reasonable test file: delete every package you can delete while still showing the error, however if I run your example i get no error other than the missing png file

Comment: also the log file will show which file you have locally that has the mal formed \ProvidesPackageRCS  but you have only shown a small fragment so we can not see which package is in error.

Comment: I use miktex, and png is an image, but it doesn't really matter the error that i have it's in line 11 shows that paragraph ended before provides package rsc ain't comprehend that very well.

Comment: It is up to _you_ to provide a test file that people can run to debug the error, if the image is not needed to show the error _delete it from the example_ also do you really need `txfonts` or `multicol` to show the error, delete every packag ethat you can delete to make it easier to debug. but as I say show the log file which will show which file is in error.,

Comment: thank u i solved the problem the package that i used where those: \usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
%Paquetes necesarios para tablas
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortab} but do u know what package can i use for make tables?

Comment: Check if there are updates (as user and as admin), the error message indicates an too old pstricks package.

Comment: I assume that this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470034/pstricks-add-sty-error so updating pstricks should fix it.