# An error in pgf libraries after an update

Tags: tikz-pgf, pst-plot, miktex-update

I made an update in my miktex system today on windows 8.1, without saving the old one (which is a very bad idea, I know !).

When I com[ile the following document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
A MWE
\end{document}
```

I obtain the following the log file with an error message (`mfbellalouna` is my username: (here is a great part of it, because the program enables only 30000 character)...

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.1.14)  14 JAN 2019 23:11
entering extended mode
**./Try-MWE-pgf.tex
(Try-MWE-pgf.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\book.c
ls"
Document Class: book 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\bk12.c
lo"
File: bk12.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@chapter=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@subparagraph=\count86
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pst-plot\ps
t-plot.sty"
Package: pst-plot 2011/06/05 v1.00 LaTeX wrapper for `pst-plot' (HV)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pstricks\ps
tricks.sty"
Package: pstricks 2018/12/21 v0.69 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/iftex\iftex
.sty"
Package: iftex 2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX, 
and LuaTeX
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\shell
esc.sty"
Package: shellesc 2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 69.
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcol
or.sty"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cf
g\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 225.

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-de
f\xetex.def"
File: xetex.def 2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\p
st-xkey.tex"
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xke
yval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\x
keyval.tex"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\x
kvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\k
eyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count89
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\
pstricks.tex"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\
pst-fp.tex" `pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv)
\pstFP@xs=\count90
\pstFP@xia=\count91
\pstFP@xib=\count92
\pstFP@xfa=\count93
\pstFP@xfb=\count94
\pstFP@rega=\count95
\pstFP@regb=\count96
\pstFP@regs=\count97
\pstFP@times=\count98
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utili
ties\pgfutil-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utili
ties\pgfutil-common-lists.tex"))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utili
ties\pgfkeys.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utili
ties\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utili
ties\pgffor.code.tex"

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 \ProvidesPackageRCS[v\pgfversion] $H
                                         eader: /cvsroot/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf...

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


Package: pst-plot 2011/04/13 package wrapper for pst-plot.tex (hv)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pst-plot\
pst-plot.tex"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pst-tools
\pst-tools.tex" `PST-tools' v0.09b, 2017/12/03 (hv))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks-
add\pstricks-add.tex"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pst-node\
pst-node.tex"  v1.41, 2017/12/30
\psrow=\count122
\pscol=\count123
\psmatrixcnt=\count124
\psrowsep=\skip43
\pscolsep=\skip44
\pst@args=\count125
\num@pts=\count126
\pst@argcnt=\count127
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pst-arrow
\pst-arrow.tex" `pst-arrow' v0.01, 2016/09/01 (dr,hv)
\pshooklength=\dimen141
\pshookwidth=\dimen142
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pst-3d\ps
t-3d.tex" `PST-3d' v1.11, 2010/02/14 (tvz))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pst-math\
pst-math.tex" `pst-math' v0.63 , (CJ,hv))
`pstricks-add' v3.85a, 2018/02/03 (dr,hv)
\psparallelogramsep=\dimen143
\pst@cntC=\count128
\pst@stepcount=\count129
\chart@ColorIndex=\dimen144
\chart@ColorStep=\dimen145
\pst@chartHeight=\dimen146
\pst@chartStackDepth=\dimen147
\pst@chartStackWidth=\dimen148
\chart@Toggle=\count130
\psVectorCtr=\count131
)  v1.91, 2018/08/31 (tvz,hv)
\pstRadUnit=\dimen149
\pstRadUnitInv=\dimen150
\pst@linecnt=\count132
\RCD@file=\read1
\psxlabelsep=\dimen151
\psylabelsep=\dimen152
\psk@subticksize=\dimen153
\pst@xticksizeA=\dimen154
\pst@xticksizeB=\dimen155
\pst@xticksizeC=\dimen156
\pst@yticksizeA=\dimen157
\pst@yticksizeB=\dimen158
\pst@yticksizeC=\dimen159
\@digitcounter=\count133
\psk@llx=\dimen160
\psk@lly=\dimen161
\psk@urx=\dimen162
\psk@ury=\dimen163
\pst@xunit=\dimen164
\pst@yunit=\dimen165
)
File: pst-plot.tex 2018/08/31 1.91 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv)
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgfplots\pg
fplots.sty"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\
pgfplots.revision.tex")
Package: pgfplots 2018/03/28 v1.16 Data Visualization (1.16)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\gr
aphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\gr
aphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\tr
ig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cf
g\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 99.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen166
\Gin@req@width=\dimen167
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/fronten
dlayer\tikz.sty"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/basicla
yer\pgf.sty"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utiliti
es\pgfrcs.sty"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utili
ties\pgfutil-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks29
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen168
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen169

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utili
ties\pgfutil-common-lists.tex"))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utili
ties\pgfutil-latex.def"
\pgfutil@abb=\box31

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ms\everyshi
.sty"
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utili
ties\pgfrcs.code.tex"
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/basicla
yer\pgfcore.sty"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/systeml
ayer\pgfsys.sty"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/syste
mlayer\pgfsys.code.tex"
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utili
ties\pgfkeys.code.tex")
\pgf@x=\dimen170
\pgf@y=\dimen171
\pgf@xa=\dimen172
\pgf@ya=\dimen173
\pgf@xb=\dimen174
\pgf@yb=\dimen175
\pgf@xc=\dimen176
\pgf@yc=\dimen177
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count134
\c@pgf@countb=\count135
\c@pgf@countc=\count136
\c@pgf@countd=\count137
\t@pgf@toka=\toks30
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks31
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks32

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/syste
mlayer\pgf.cfg"
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-xetex.def

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/syste
mlayer\pgfsys-xetex.def"
File: pgfsys-xetex.def 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.11)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/syste
mlayer\pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def"
File: pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.14)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/syste
mlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def"
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)
\pgfsys@objnum=\count138
)))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/syste
mlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex"
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count139
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count140
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/syste
mlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex"
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcore.code.tex"
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\
pgfmath.code.tex")
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen178
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen179
\pgf@picminy=\dimen180
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen181
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen182
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen183
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen184
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen185
\pgf@xx=\dimen186
\pgf@xy=\dimen187
\pgf@yx=\dimen188
\pgf@yy=\dimen189
\pgf@zx=\dimen190
\pgf@zy=\dimen191
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen192
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen193
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcorepathusage.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen194
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen195
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex"
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box32
\pgf@hbox=\box33
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box34
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count141
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex"
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen196
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcoretransformations.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen197
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen198
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen199
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcorequick.code.tex"
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex"
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen256
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen257
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count142
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box35
))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex"
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcoretransparency.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basic
layer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/modul
es\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex"
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21  (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box36
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/modul
es\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex"
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/compati
bility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen258
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen259
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/compati
bility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utiliti
es\pgffor.sty"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utiliti
es\pgfkeys.sty"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utili
ties\pgfkeys.code.tex"))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/math\pg
fmath.sty"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\
pgfmath.code.tex"))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utili
ties\pgffor.code.tex"
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\
pgfmath.code.tex")
\pgffor@iter=\dimen260
\pgffor@skip=\dimen261
\pgffor@stack=\toks33
\pgffor@toks=\toks34
))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/front
endlayer/tikz\tikz.code.tex"
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/libra
ries\pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex"
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count143
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen262
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen263
\tikz@lasty=\dimen264
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen265
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen266
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen267
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen268
\tikz@figbox=\box37
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box38
\tikz@tempbox=\box39
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box40
\tikztreelevel=\count144
\tikznumberofchildren=\count145
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count146
\tikz@fig@count=\count147

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/modul
es\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex"
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count148
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count149
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count150
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count151

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/front
endlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\
pgfplots.code.tex"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\
pgfplotscore.code.tex"
\t@pgfplots@toka=\toks35
\t@pgfplots@tokb=\toks36
\t@pgfplots@tokc=\toks37
\pgfplots@tmpa=\dimen269
\c@pgfplots@coordindex=\count152
\c@pgfplots@scanlineindex=\count153

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
sys\pgfplotssysgeneric.code.tex"))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
libs\pgfplotslibrary.code.tex")
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
oldpgfcompatib\pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_loader.code.tex"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/libra
ries\pgflibraryfpu.code.tex")
Package pgfplots: loading complementary arithmetics for your pgf version...

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
oldpgfcompatib\pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgflibraryfpu.code.tex")
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
oldpgfcompatib\pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgfmathfloat.code.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count154
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
oldpgfcompatib\pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_leq.code.tex"))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
util\pgfplotsutil.code.tex"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
liststructure\pgfplotsliststructure.code.tex")
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
liststructure\pgfplotsliststructureext.code.tex")
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
liststructure\pgfplotsarray.code.tex"
\c@pgfplotsarray@tmp=\count155
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
liststructure\pgfplotsmatrix.code.tex")
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
numtable\pgfplotstableshared.code.tex"
\c@pgfplotstable@counta=\count156
\t@pgfplotstable@a=\toks38
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
liststructure\pgfplotsdeque.code.tex")
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
util\pgfplotsbinary.code.tex"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
util\pgfplotsbinary.data.code.tex"))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
util\pgfplotsutil.verb.code.tex")
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
libs\pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.code.tex"
\c@pgfplotslibrarysurf@no=\count157

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
sys\pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.pgfsys-xetex.def"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
sys\pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def"
\c@pgfplotslibrarysurf@streamlen=\count158
))))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
util\pgfplotscolormap.code.tex"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
util\pgfplotscolor.code.tex"))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\
pgfplotsstackedplots.code.tex")
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\
pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\
pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.tex"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\
pgfplotsmeshplotimage.code.tex")))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\
pgfplots.scaling.code.tex")
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\
pgfplotscoordprocessing.code.tex")
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\
pgfplots.errorbars.code.tex")
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\
pgfplots.markers.code.tex")
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\
pgfplotsticks.code.tex")
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\
pgfplots.paths.code.tex")
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/front
endlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/modul
es\pgfmoduledecorations.code.tex"
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen270
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen271
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen272
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen273
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen274
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count159
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen275
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen276
)
\tikz@lib@dec@box=\box41
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/front
endlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/libra
ries/decorations\pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex"))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/front
endlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/libra
ries/decorations\pgflibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex"))
\pgfplots@numplots=\count160
\pgfplots@xmin@reg=\dimen277
\pgfplots@xmax@reg=\dimen278
\pgfplots@ymin@reg=\dimen279
\pgfplots@ymax@reg=\dimen280
\pgfplots@zmin@reg=\dimen281
\pgfplots@zmax@reg=\dimen282
)
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/front
endlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex"
File: tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/libra
ries\pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex"
File: pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2015/08/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.14)
)))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgfplots\pg
fplotstable.sty"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\
pgfplots.revision.tex")
Package: pgfplotstable 2018/03/28 v1.16 Table typesetting and Pretty-printing (
1.16)

("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
numtable\pgfplotstable.code.tex"
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/
numtable\pgfplotstable.coltype.code.tex"))
("C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\array
.sty"
Package: array 2018/12/30 v2.4k Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen283
\ar@mcellbox=\box42
\extrarowheight=\dimen284
\NC@list=\toks39
\extratabsurround=\skip45
\backup@length=\skip46
\ar@cellbox=\box43
)) (Try-MWE-pgf.aux)
\openout1 = `Try-MWE-pgf.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
 ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} into 
your preamble.
 on input line 6.

[1

] (Try-MWE-pgf.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 24507 strings out of 427748
 622770 string characters out of 3145688
 897544 words of memory out of 5000000
 28173 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 6392 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 62i,5n,96p,710b,479s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on Try-MWE-pgf.pdf (1 page).
```

and the following pdf file

[image]
When I comment the command `\usepackage{pst-plot}` it compiles without any problem....

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Make sure to run the updater/console again in user and admin mode. This is quite probably related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469005/35864

Comment: I have only one version. It's my personal computer, and I used the updater of the Miktex console

Comment: In that case it would help if you could provide a short example document/MWE that reproduces the error.

Comment: The $ are correct DO NOT edit TeX engine code ensure your up to date in console First close editor and run console as if admin and second (or first if not dual) as single user. Tasks refresh FNDB and font maps in all (both) cases. exit and restart

Comment: How can I refresh  font maps?

Comment: If you have a dual system (not recommended) you will have the option when starting MiKTeX-console to switch to admin do an update then once that is finished at the top menu are the follow up TASKS to doubly stabilise the new updates. if you did all those as admin you need to do the same as simple user as well.

Comment: Would you see the MWE edited please

Comment: The example file compiles without an error for me on a fully updated MikTeX 2.9 (Win 10). If you still get an error, please show us the full `.log` file of the LaTeX run on the MWE. Please make absolutely sure that you have run all possible update steps.

Comment: It is perhaps due to that I'm under windows 8.1 then !

Comment: I doubt it. It must be an outdated package file. If it is not solved by an update (in user and admin mode), then maybe you have a manual installation lying around. Please add the full `.log` of the run to your question.

Comment: I can't add the full log file because it is out of range... 30000 characters...

Comment: The current version of PGF on MikTeX is `pgf 2019/01/05 v3.1 (3.1)`, but you have `pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a`. That clearly shows that the update did not work as intended. You have a MikTeX installation in `C:\Users\mfbellalouna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9`, there should be a way to update that.

Comment: ok thank you. I'll try to update manually the package, but I don't understand why it was not done automatically ! Where can I find a trace of the updates  please ?

Comment: Yes it was a problem of update. would you make an answer to my question please. Many thanks for your disponibility