# Incompatibility between PGF and PStricks

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, pstricks, incompatibility

With the new packages, I get an error message for every tex-file using PStricks. It seems to be a compatibility problem between new versions of pgf and pstricks. I tried to solve the problem by using an old version of PStricks, following advices from this post : [PSTricks: Newly introduced error in package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469005/pstricks-newly-introduced-error-in-package) , but the error remains.

Here is the message I get, in short :

```
Paragraph ended before \ProvidesPackageRCS@i was complete. \par l.11
```

And in length :

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pstricks\pstricks.sty"
Package: pstricks 2018/12/21 v0.69 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
and LuaTeX
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty"
Package: shellesc 2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 69.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\pst-xkey.tex"
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks48
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks49
)
\XKV@depth=\count339
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)))
(pstricks.tex ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.tex"
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv)
\pstFP@xs=\count340
\pstFP@xia=\count341
\pstFP@xib=\count342
\pstFP@xfa=\count343
\pstFP@xfb=\count344
\pstFP@rega=\count345
\pstFP@regb=\count346
\pstFP@regs=\count347
\pstFP@times=\count348
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks50
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen266
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen267
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex"
Runaway argument?
] {pgffor.code.tex}
! Paragraph ended before \ProvidesPackageRCS@i was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.11
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex")
\pgffor@iter=\dimen268
\pgffor@skip=\dimen269
\pgffor@stack=\toks51
\pgffor@toks=\toks52
)
\psLoopIndex=\count349
`PSTricks' v2.92 <2018/12/27> (tvz,hv)
\pst@dima=\dimen270
\pst@dimb=\dimen271
\pst@dimc=\dimen272
\pst@dimd=\dimen273
\pst@dimg=\dimen274
\pst@dimh=\dimen275
\pst@dimm=\dimen276
\pst@dimn=\dimen277
\pst@dimo=\dimen278
\pst@dimp=\dimen279
\pst@hbox=\box82
\pst@ibox=\box83
\pst@boxg=\box84
\pst@cnta=\count350
\pst@cntb=\count351
\pst@cntc=\count352
\pst@cntd=\count353
\pst@cntg=\count354
\pst@cnth=\count355
\pst@cntm=\count356
\pst@cntn=\count357
\pst@cnto=\count358
\pst@cntp=\count359
\@zero=\count360
\pst@toks=\toks53
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pstricks.con")
\psunit=\dimen280
\psxunit=\dimen281
\psyunit=\dimen282
\pst@C@@rType=\count361
\pslinewidth=\dimen283
\psk@startLW=\dimen284
\psk@endLW=\dimen285
\pst@customdefs=\toks54
\pslinearc=\dimen286
\pst@symbolStep=\dimen287
\pst@symbolWidth=\dimen288
\pst@symbolLinewidth=\dimen289
\everypsbox=\toks55
\psframesep=\dimen290
\pslabelsep=\dimen291
\sh@wgridXunit=\dimen292
\sh@wgridYunit=\dimen293
\pst@shift=\dimen294
)
File: pstricks.tex 2018/12/27 v2.92 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.tex")
File: pst-fp.tex 2018/12/27 v2.92 `PST-fp' (hv)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pst-grad\pst-grad.sty"
Package: pst-grad 2004/07/15 package wrapper for pst-grad.tex (hv)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pst-grad\pst-grad.tex"
`pst-grad' v1.06, 2006/11/27 (tvz,dg,hv))
File: pst-grad.tex 2006/11/27 1.06 `pst-grad' (tvz)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgfplots\pgfplots.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.revision.tex")
Package: pgfplots 2018/03/28 v1.16 Data Visualization (1.16)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex"
Runaway argument?
] {pgffor.code.tex}
! Paragraph ended before \ProvidesPackageRCS@i was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.11
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex")
\pgffor@iter=\dimen295
\pgffor@skip=\dimen296
\pgffor@stack=\toks56
\pgffor@toks=\toks57
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\tikz.code.tex"
Runaway argument?
] {tikz.code.tex}
! Paragraph ended before \ProvidesPackageRCS@i was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.11
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.
code.tex"
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2019/01/05 v3.1 (3.1)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count362
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen297
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen298
\tikz@lasty=\dimen299
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen300
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen301
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen302
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen303
\tikz@figbox=\box85
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box86
\tikz@tempbox=\box87
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box88
\tikztreelevel=\count363
\tikznumberofchildren=\count364
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count365
\tikz@fig@count=\count366
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex"
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2019/01/05 v3.1 (3.1)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count367
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count368
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count369
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count370
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikz
librarytopaths.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2019/01/05 v3.1 (3.1)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotscore.code.tex"
\t@pgfplots@toka=\toks58
\t@pgfplots@tokb=\toks59
\t@pgfplots@tokc=\toks60
\pgfplots@tmpa=\dimen304
\c@pgfplots@coordindex=\count371
\c@pgfplots@scanlineindex=\count372
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/sys\pgfplotssysgeneric.code.
tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/libs\pgfplotslibrary.code.te
x")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib\pgfplotsoldpg
fsupp_loader.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryfpu.code.tex"
)
Package pgfplots: loading complementary arithmetics for your pgf version...
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib\pgfplotsoldpg
fsupp_pgflibraryfpu.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib\pgfplotsoldpg
fsupp_pgfmathfloat.code.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count373
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotsutil.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure\pgfplotslistst
ructure.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure\pgfplotslistst
ructureext.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure\pgfplotsarray.
code.tex"
\c@pgfplotsarray@tmp=\count374
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure\pgfplotsmatrix
.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable\pgfplotstableshared
.code.tex"
\c@pgfplotstable@counta=\count375
\t@pgfplotstable@a=\toks61
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure\pgfplotsdeque.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotsbinary.code.tex
"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotsbinary.data.cod
e.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotsutil.verb.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/libs\pgflibrarypgfplots.surf
shading.code.tex"
\c@pgfplotslibrarysurf@no=\count376
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/sys\pgflibrarypgfplots.surfs
hading.pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def"
\c@pgfplotslibrarysurf@streamlen=\count377
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotscolormap.code.t
ex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplotscolor.code.tex"
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsstackedplots.code.te
x")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsplothandlers.code.te
x"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code
.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsmeshplotimage.code.t
ex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.scaling.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotscoordprocessing.code
.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.errorbars.code.tex"
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.markers.code.tex"
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsticks.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.paths.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikz
librarydecorations.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduledecorations.code
.tex"
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen305
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen306
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen307
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen308
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen309
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count378
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen310
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen311
)
\tikz@lib@dec@box=\box89
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikz
librarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations\pgflibraryd
ecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikz
librarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations\pgflibraryd
ecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex"))
\pgfplots@numplots=\count379
\pgfplots@xmin@reg=\dimen312
\pgfplots@xmax@reg=\dimen313
\pgfplots@ymin@reg=\dimen314
\pgfplots@ymax@reg=\dimen315
\pgfplots@zmin@reg=\dimen316
\pgfplots@zmax@reg=\dimen317
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikz
libraryplotmarks.code.tex"
File: tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2019/01/05 v3.1 (3.1)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplotmarks.cod
e.tex"
File: pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2019/01/05 v3.1 (3.1)
)))
\c@defi=\count380
\c@meth=\count381
\c@metho=\count382
\c@prop=\count383
```

Comment: Make sure to update your TeX distribution again. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864. Remove any local copies of the files from packages involved from your working directory. Make sure you have not manually altered any files from the installed packages.

Comment: Yes, I just edited the first message.

Comment: I tried to select the relevant part of the file. The whole thing was too long.

Comment: The `.log` file suggests you have a local version of `pstricks.tex` in the same folder as your main TeX file (as suggested in the linked answer). Remove it and update your system. (You have ```PSTricks' v2.92 <2018/12/27> (tvz,hv)```, but current is `PSTricks' v2.95 <2019/01/22> (tvz,hv)`)

Answer (score -1):

You should just be able to edit the file `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex` and comment out the line `\ProvidesPackageRCS{pgffor.code.tex}`.