# Error simply by including the pstricks-add package

Tags: errors, pstricks

This is a minimal working example of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

By removing the \usepackage{pstricks-add}, everything works properly. With this line in the code, however, I obtain the error:

```
! Paragraph ended before \ProvidesPackageRCS@i was complete.<to be read 
again>\par
```

I have read another thread with the same problem, but there, the answers suggest waiting a few days for the bug to be fixed. The thread, however, was placed a month ago. And I have installed texmaker and MikTex this week.

Also, I can't find older versions of the pstricks-add package to replace the one installed right now.

Has anyone solved this problem yet?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Make sure to run your MikTeX updater in admin *and* user mode at least twice: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864. This is very likely caused by a version conflict between packages in your user tree and your global tree. An update in both modes should make sure that the packages in both trees have matching versions again. This 'you have to update in both modes' issue is one of the reason why many people recommend against multi-user MikTeX installations and suggest a single-user setup instead.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469005/35864 of which this question is probably a duplicate.

Comment: BTW: Depending on the way you installed MikTeX you may not have actually gotten the newest updates when you installed it (some packages that came bundled with the installed might have been older). That's why it is usually recommended to run full updates after you installed MikTeX. Just for completeness I should mention that the MWE compiles without errors for me on a MikTeX system updated yesterday morning.

Comment: Does that mean the issue was solved by updating?

Comment: Yes. Updating solved the issue. Since I had downloaded and installed texmaker and Miktex this week I thought it would already be the latest version, but updating was indeed required. Once again, thank you very much.

Comment: Very well, voted to close as a duplicate then.