# pgffor.code.tex Error?

Tags: miktex, compilation-error, pgffor

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{undertilde}
\usepackage{enumerate, multicol}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{polynom,xpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}
```

I get error on line 11 file: `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.code.tex`

Message:

> ```
> ! Paragraph ended before \ProvidesPackageRCS@i was complete.
> <to be read again>
> \par
> l.11
> I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
> control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
> My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
> ```

I updated my MiKTeX and Texmaker and I got the same error now I get the same error even on my previous version (which worked just fine before update).

Comment: update your TeX-Distribution! See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469005/pstricks-newly-introduced-error-in-package

Comment: You should always update miktex in user *and* admin mode.

Answer (score -1):

You should just be able to edit `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.code.tex` and comment out line 11. Everything should work fine without that file having the `ProvidesPackageRCS` line.