# ProvidepackageRCS

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{epsfig,rotating,times,psfrag,pstricks,tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor,array,graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
 \small
 \psfrag{4} [c][c]{~~4}
 \psfrag{6} [c][c]{6}
 \psfrag{8} [c][c]{8}
 \psfrag{10} [c][c]{10}
 \psfrag{12} [c][c]{12}
 \psfrag{14} [c][c]{14~~}


\centerline{\includegraphics[width=100mm]{figure1.eps}}

\begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)
 \put(0,190){~~0}
 \put(0,170){-10}
 \put(0,150){-20}
 \put(0,130){-30}
 \put(0,110){-40}
 \put(0,90){-50}

  \put(58, 20){$\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{yx}}$}
  \put(105, 20){$\mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{xy}}$}


 \put(-12,147){\makebox(0,0)[it]{\begin{sideways}{\normalize Reflection (dB)}\end{sideways}}}
 \put(159,-5){\makebox(0,0)[ct]{\normalize Frequency (GHz)}}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \path(0,0) coordinate (origin);
 \draw[very thick,blue](1.2, 0.8)--++(.75,0);
 \draw[dash pattern={on 6pt off 2.5pt on 6pt off 2.5pt},very thick,red](2.9, 0.8)--++(0.75,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{picture}
 \end{document}
```

when I compile my  above document I recieve the error `/providepackageRCS[v/pgfversion] $Header:/cvsroot/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf...` dont know how to deal with it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: Are you sure that the pgf package is correctly installed ?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469005/pstricks-newly-introduced-error-in-package

Comment: as noted in the linked message this was a temporary issue last year so should be fixed if you update tikz/pgf